# Can I work remotely for a German company from India being an Indian Citizen?

Tags: germany, indian-citizens, india

A startup company in Berlin, Germany is interested to have an interview with me for a Position which states is Fully Remote. I am an Indian residing in India.

Can I work for this company completely remotely?

Comment: You may become liable for both German and Indian income taxes.

Comment: Also their "fully remote" can only mean "fully remote in Germany only", so also better to check that.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Thank you for highlighting this. I will have a detailed discussion with the company :)

Comment: @quantum Thank you for highlighting this. I will have a detailed discussion with the company :)

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that a German company may not be the most accurate source of information about possible Indian tax liability for an Indian citizen, physically present in India, who works remotely for a German firm. I would seek info from an Indian accountant on this issue.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I had a chat with HR. They said I will be hired as a Freelancer and tax will be applied as per Indian Rules. I believe being hired as a Freelancer would not be a good idea. Any thoughts on that. By Remote they definitely mean work from anywhere and If I am interested they will help me move to Germany.

Comment: HR is focused only on your relations to the company. HR's expertise does not extend to your relation with the German or Indian (or any other country's) taxing authority. While HR probably knows about tax liability for an employee or freelancer who is resident in Germany, I would not depend upon their assurances with regard to possible tax liability (to either Germany or India) if you are not resident in Germany.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Sure. I will discuss tax implications with a CA before I accept the job offer. Thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica If they offer remote jobs, they almost certainly have some HR solution to “employ” people locally. You're technically correct that income tax is also your responsibility but employment in Germany (and many other places) requires tax withholding, checking your employees' right to reside in the country, collecting a lot of mandatory insurance fees, and potentially a lot of liability for the employer.

Comment: This means a company cannot realistically offer a regular work contract and ignore the fact the OP cannot provide proof of residence in Germany. If they advertise a job as remote, they almost certainly have other contractual arrangements in mind (from a completely vanilla employment contract with a local branch in India to somewhat more questionable pretend contract work or employer of record solutions).

Comment: In other words: HR can be unable to provide advice to the odd employee trying to move abroad from a regular office but they cannot ignore the issues in a remote-first work-from-anywhere company or even for a startup with more than a couple of employees out-of-country. If hiring remotely is part of your growth strategy, you need to assist new hires with this and it is becoming increasingly common.

Comment: Actually, I was also in same situation as you are in, If you have got any solution can you please share it with me, here is my gmail: jaydippawar.co.in@gmail.com , we can discuss on that and you can give me your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The liability is mostly for the company in these scenarios. Nearly every company advertising jobs as fully remote will either have restrictions on where their employees can be located or figure out some solution to offer you some form of local contract. It could be something like a contractor/freelance contract or a work contract with a third-party “employer of record” provider. It's up to you to decide if that's similar enough to an employment contract for your taste.

Some companies with a lot of experience with this (e.g. GitLab) also rule out employment in specific countries because there is no satisfactory legal vehicle and too much liability for the company in those countries. A startup will almost certainly rely on a third-party HR solution vendor to handle all this (and your contract is likely to be with that company or one of their subcontractors, rather than directly with the startup).

If they are not, I would consider this a red flag. I would not be terribly concerned about taxes but rather about the fact that someone might discover down the line that they cannot offer you a contract or be forced to end it when they clean up their processes.

In practice, you should know that this is possible and you don't need to rule them out before the first interview. You can always ask questions (maybe ask if they have other employees in India or outside Germany in general?) and you will still have the option to pull out when they send you an actual contract and have a chance to see how it looks like.

One downside to keep in mind is that the contract you will get is likely to be less protective than a *bona fide* German employment contract. It will be easier to fire you than if you were employed in Germany with a full-time permanent contract (but then again, it's not worse than typical at-will US employment or the many temp work contracts that exist in Europe).

Comment: Thank you for information :)

Answer (score 1):

You likely wouldn't be able to become an employee, unless that German company also has offices in India and would handle tax-related and other local law-related things there. But you could be a freelancer and be on a freelance contract. Then basically you have your own one-man company in India and pay taxes on your income through that.

Comment: That would be good until and unless company fulfils financial obligations every month without fail right?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I work for this company completely remotely?

If you have a German work permit and reside in Germany, you can. The job offer might even help you *get* you those permits.

If you have a German work permit and reside in India and pay taxes, social security and health insurance *in both countries*, you can. But that is a tax nightmare and since the company has to handle parts of that, they might not be willing to spend that time and money.

What you *cannot* do is stay in India and work remotely for a German company as a regular full time employee without a German work permit or paying German taxes/socials/health insurance.

The German company is not allowed to employ you without a work permit and the fact that you don't have a social security number, tax identity or a mandatory German health insurance number will make that abundantly clear once they even try to fill out forms.

What they *can* do is to employ you at an Indian subsidiary of theirs as an Indian employee, if they have one. Big corporations might do that, as a startup that seems highly unlikely.

What they can also do, is to not employ you as a regular employee, but instead as an independent contractor. That means you work for them, but you don't get a salary. Instead you send them an invoice each month for the services you provided. In your case maybe hours of programming at a set rate. However, that means you have zero legal protections that would apply to German workers. No paid time off, no holidays, no paid sick leave, nothing. You get paid for services provided and only that. It also means you have to somehow incorporate in India to be able to send invoices to other corporate entities. If they decide to not pay those invoices, you will have next to zero leverage, since they could care less what an Indidan court decides if they have no business in India.

If they are a tiny startup, whether *they* know this... is up to your best guess. Ask them how they plan on doing it. Make sure they know what they are doing, before you quit any other job you may have.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Are issues outlined apply only for a German Company or any company in Europe in general.

Comment: "Europe" consists of around 50 different countries, half of them in the EU and the rest with varying degrees of sub-treaties with the EU for different parts, like taxes or freedom of movement. Some of them share a currency, but not all. So "Europe" is in no way one big bloc with the same rules. But I would expect them to have very similar laws. What I described as working above should work in all countries, but whether any of them has loopholes around it that makes it easier to be employed directly, you would need specialized knowledge about each of them, that I don't have.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs.