# Remote work from Germany for Polish company

Tags: germany, taxes, employment, insurance, poland

### tl;dr

What are valid setups for cross-border employments in the EU?

### Situation

I am **living in Germany** and am about to sign an employment contract (as a programmer) with a smaller company in **Poland**.

The work is purely **remote** (from Germany) and the company has **no legal branch in Germany** whatsoever, just Poland. They originally wanted to hire me as contractor/sole entrepreneur, but I declined that.

I wanted to have a solution that is simple for me, i.e. being a regular employee of their company, not having to fill out any tax papers while still having the benefit of all the standard german benefits of being in an employment. That is:

- pension insurance
- unemployment insurance
- health insurance

They said that they will figure something out and later claimed to have found a setup that works.

### Question

I am still trying to get them to explain me the setup, but wanted to get some feedback from the community in the meantime.

What could be a valid solution to this situation, given that they do not have a legal branch in Germany, nor me being a sole entrepreneur?

Comment: See https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/179581/remote-offer-freelancer-contract-with-benefits/179599#179599, https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/non-eu-citizen-working-for-austrian-company-in-austria-and-has-main-residence-in/24378#24378, or https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/23844/can-i-work-remotely-for-a-german-company-from-india-being-an-indian-citizen/23854#23854 for related questions.

Comment: did you have an answer?

Comment: Nope. I signed the contract and was hired as _regular employer_ and the company figured out the details with the german government. They do pay all my insurances and tax. I am not sure what exactly they did on the legal side, but it seems to work.